# How to run .exe file with additional commands in python?

Tags: python, windows, exe

I want to launch Valorant (it's a game) we can't run it directly from the .exe file we have to run by adding few lines at the end of the .exe file as shown below.

"D:\Games\Riot Games\Riot Client\RiotClientServices.exe" --launch-product=valorant --launch-patchline=live

I tried this(didn't work):

```
                if 'valorant' in query:
                os.startfile("D:\\Games\\Riot Games\\Riot Client\\RiotClientServices.exe" --launch-product=valorant --launch-patchline=live )
                speak('okay')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html

There is an example with an argument like this:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `subprocess.run([path, command, command])` would work.

In your code it would be:

```py
import subprocess
                if 'valorant' in query:
                subprocess.run(["D:\\Games\\Riot Games\\Riot Client\\RiotClientServices.exe", "--launch-product=valorant", "--launch-patchline=live"])
                speak('okay')
```

Comment: ```subprocess.run``` is the newer version of ```subprocess.call```, so i suggest to check if ```subprocess.run``` is in your python version. 3.5 or greater i think